# iTunes "Home Sharing" doesn't work with Apple Lossless files

Tags: itunes, home-sharing

I'm wondering whether anyone else has had problems with iTunes Home Sharing working with Apple Lossless formated audio files?

I have iTunes 10.2.1 on both machines and it will not even start to play lossless music, only MP3 and other lossy formats.

I'm wondering whether anyone else has any workarounds or if this is just the way it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes Home Sharing works for me to send playable Apple Lossless songs to iPhone / iPad and another Mac streaming songs.

There may be a problem with your setup since it is supposed to work and does for me. Perhaps someone else will chime in with their experience - but I have seen it work recently at several friend's houses as well as in my setup.

I'm fairly certain I would have noticed a problem back at 10.2.1 as much of my Beatles collection is stored in lossless format but I'm not 100% certain there wasn't a bug in a previous version of iTunes.

You could rule that out by upgrading to the latest iTunes 10.3.1.

I am guessing there is another problem but am at a loss to guess what it might be without more information on your setup.

Comment: I'll give it another try this evening and see if I have any better luck.

Comment: I hope it works!

Comment: Just following up, it seems to be working for me now.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a pointer to a possible clue. I read in [this discussion in Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2710722?start=0&tstart=0) that there may be a problem with iTunes Home Sharing not recognizing certain files because of particular extended meta tags attached to them. Editing and changing the meta tags enables iTunes Home Sharing to work with them.